# Matlab-how can I use SSIM function using sprintf function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, printf, interpolation, ssim

Now I'm researching on Image processing about interpolation. So I invented my new interpolation algorithms about image.

And I have to check SSIM value about my images that are interpolated by my interpolation algorithms.

Now I'm using ICY tool (On windows, GUI environment) but this tool is too hard to check large amount of images because of GUI interface.

So I want to check image SSIM value using matlab ssim function.

but I'm not a expert in matlab language, so I'm in trouble in dealing with import various name to ssim function.

This is what I want to do:

1. I want to checks ssim value with a large amount of images.
2. So I'm going to use sprintf function to make a valuable image name.
3. The third I want to import this input image name to ssim function.

This is the code I used.

```
for n= 1 : 10
str = sprintf('./x2/cutted/x2_fn%d_4p_3p_cutted.bmp',n);
str_ori = sprintf('ori_%d.bmp',n);

img_cutted=imread(str);
img_ori=(str_ori);

[ssimval,ssimmap]=ssim(str,str_ori);
end
```

When I use this code, the error is invoked.

> Error: The str must be the types of uint8, uint16, int16, single, double.
>   but you used char value.

After I got this message, write "uint8 str;" but still the message is invoked.

Comment: you mean `ssim(img,img_ori)`? Where do you get the error?

Comment: yes!, ssim(omg,img_ori) <- here is the error point

Comment: I think the ssim function that is provided by tool box doesn't support char value...
normally the ssim function is used like this "ssim('filename','filename');"

Comment: https://kr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ssim.html
this is the help of ssim function...
someone plz help me..!

Comment: of course the "error" is translated message, because I use matlab Korean ver. but that is the what error message said.

Comment: You use them wrong I guess. `ssim` gets 2 images as input, not 2 strings. replace your code by `[ssimval,ssimmap]=ssim(img,img_ori);`

Comment: oh... I was idiot , So thank you. I think I was just nervous about I'm using matlab. I'm good at C and verilog but matlab language.
anyway so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ssim gets 2 images as input, not 2 strings. replace your code by `[ssimval,ssimmap]=ssim(img,img_ori);`